# I have multiple python versions in ubuntu 18.04. How can I revert to the default and remove everything else?

Tags: python

So I have multiple versions of python, along with pycharm (community), anaconda, and jupyter notebook. I would like to remove and purge everything from my system except the default python that comes with ubuntu 18.04, and then reinstall Jupyter Notebook from scratch. I want to do this because I'm having issues with importing packages in Jupyter Notebook because of the multiple python versions on my machine. How do I do this?

This is the output that I get when I type `whereis python` in my terminal:

```
python: /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python3.6 
/usr/bin/python2.7 
/usr/bin/python3.6m-config 
/usr/bin/python 
/usr/bin/python2.7-config 
/usr/bin/python3.6-config 
/usr/lib/python3.6 
/usr/lib/python2.7 
/usr/lib/python3.7 
/etc/python3.6 
/etc/python2.7 
/etc/python 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6 
/usr/local/lib/python2.7 
/usr/include/python3.6m 
/usr/include/python3.6 
/usr/include/python2.7 
/usr/share/python 
/home/<username>/anaconda3/bin/python3.7m 
/home/<username>/anaconda3/bin/python 
/home/<username>/anaconda3/bin/python3.7 
/home/<username>/anaconda3/bin/python3.7-config 
/home/<username>/anaconda3/bin/python3.7m-config 
/usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: How to properly remove something depends entirely upon how you originally installed it. If you recall what you installed and how you installed it, then we can help. Otherwise, a backup-and-reinstall may be faster and easier. This sort of problem is precisely why some folks like to use disposable VMs or containers for their special environments

Comment: Thanks. I don't remember how I installed them. Is there a way to know which version of python comes pre-installed with Ubuntu 18.04? I was thinking of just keeping that one and then removing everything else through "sudo apt-get autoremove" and "snap remove"

Comment: Use `apt-cache madison python3` to learn the original version of Python3 included in your Ubuntu system.